# Make constant value asserts its logic

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to assert the variable logic on its definition?

For example:

```
import React from 'react'

type TDataType = {
    my?: {
        very?: {
            complex?: {
                structure: boolean;
            }
        }
    }
}

const data: TDataType = {
    my: {
        very: {
            complex: {
                structure: true
            }
        }
    }
}

function render() {
    const hasStructure = data && data.my && data.my.very && data.my.very.complex && data.my.very.complex.structure;
    
    return (
        <div>
            {hasStructure && (
                <div>{data.my.very.complex.structure}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Typescript will complain about the path `data.my.very.complex` being possibly undefined—but the variable above should suffice for testing the whole path.

Is there a way to write a helper, maybe using `asserts`, to avoid this? So I don't have to write:

```
<div>{data!.my!.very!.complex!.structure}</div>
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAFQBEUYU7raBeOAb1Ln7ghKAfgBcPPgKkA3JFBHjeU5QLS4wAGyQAPMRJUGBAZxhQArhjNFxAIwgQtKAHYBuSYf4Bfd8u9Tv3qRqTiZwACbMKOKMkWw0cFxKAkKKPjJylKkequpa2lnZyibmltZwpmZIaQZ+NT4B5JhmThjAEE5wRE5hcgAUAJT6OSHwABYoRgDKFaWc4ZFwAGSL8ywAdEJLKxHrQmuy8lurKBuU+xlrauB5RzsnewdnV5o6a8UWMFZIblI+RJ9QDq9ar8AA8YWA0gAfCDlNxxlMZgDaMs4MDCspwZCodw7qdzvJLrlXu9Zp5QQB6CHQ2FSfq1FSU6kwumkTxAA

Comment: I'm surprised that this isn't covered by the TS4.4 control flow analysis improvements. I guess it doesn't follow through object property access.

Comment: What would be the issue, if you just write `{data.my?.very?.complex?.structure ?? false}`. without the property check ?

Comment: @Psidom well, the issue is that we can't always make a default value. In this example, it's a simple boolean value—what if it would be an object? The idea is that by checking the variable it should assert for its underlying logic